# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tear

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Iam using selenium 2.39 and Testng
firefox version 26

below is the code

```
   package Examples;

   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   import org.junit.BeforeClass;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
   import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class Example2 {
   public static WebDriver driver;
   //String ddd;
   //    public Example2() {
   //       super();
    //    }

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass()
{
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

@Test(dataProvider="Mail Information")
public void mailSend(String to,String subject,String body) throws Exception

{

    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xyzy@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("*********");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("vO")).sendKeys(to);    
    driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys(subject);

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".editable")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@tabindex,'1') and contains(@frameborder,'0')]"))); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@role='textbox']")).sendKeys(body);    
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();       
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3']")).click();

    driver.navigate().refresh();
}

@DataProvider (name = "Mail Information")
public Object[][] mailSendProvider() 
{
    return new Object[][]

            {

            {"xyzy@gmail.com","This is a Test Mail","hello"},
            };

}

@AfterClass
public void tear()
{
    driver.quit();
   }
}
```

unable to understand problem with the test libraries or problem with Testng Setup

When iam running using TestNG, iam getting the following error.

```
 [TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1461140969\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tear
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Examples.Example2.tear(Example2.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:225)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

FAILED: mailSend("xyzy@gmail.com", "This is a Test Mail", "hello")
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Examples.Example2.mailSend(Example2.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@267b76: 34 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1ff3fcf: 145 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@1799a1e: 18 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 17 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1ddcac5: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1d35bf2: 87 ms
```

Can somebody Please help me

Comment: i see that u r importing "org.junit.BeforeClass", please change it to "org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass" and check... it worked for me

Comment: i'm adding the same as answer, do accept it to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Annotation "***BeforeClass***" is being imported from Junit && "***AfterClass***" is imported from TestNg.

Both being are different API, the error is due to referring "***AfterClass***" without defining "BeforeClass" from TestNg.

please add the following

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
```

and remove the following

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
```

hope this helps